# Could Hillary Clinton have declined to defend Thomas Taylor?

Tags: attorney-client-privilege

In 1975 Hillary Rodham was appointed to defend Thomas Alfred Taylor who was accused of raping a 12-year-old.

As a public defender, could she have refused the case? She said she didn't want to do it. What could have happened to her if she refused the case?

Answer (score 5):

**No.** She was lawfully ordered by a judge presiding over the case, and, as a member of the bar, she had no right to refuse that appointment. She did, in fact, request that the judge choose a different attorney, but that request was declined.

Sources:

[FactCheck.org - provides general background on case](http://www.factcheck.org/2016/06/clintons-1975-rape-case/)

[Arkansas Judicial Rule 8.2 - Appointment of Counsel](https://courts.arkansas.gov/rules-and-administrative-orders/court-rules/rule-82-appointment-counsel), which provides that:

> Attorneys so appointed **shall continue to represent the indigent accused until relieved for good cause or until substituted by other counsel.**

Edit: Regarding penalties for noncompliance, refusing to represent the accused would be considered criminal contempt under state law, which provides in 16-10-108(a)(3) Arkansas Code that *"willful disobedience of any process or order lawfully issued or made by it [the court]"* is punishable as a Class C Misdemeanor, at least according to 2010 law. Also, professional sanctions might be involved, IANAL so no experience there.